# MYSQL, how to retrieve row that have more than one same value with condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql which have some data as below:

```
    name      value2   
+---------+------------+
  cust A      1        
  cust A      0         
  cust B      0         
  cust B      0         
  cust C      0         
  cust D      0         
  cust D      1         
  cust E      1         
  cust E      1
```

The result i want should be as below:

```
  name      value2   
+---------+------------+
  cust B      0        
  cust C      0
```

I have tried query below but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE name IN(SELECT * FROM table WHERE value2 = 0 GROUP BY name)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for all the answer given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way, not using `group by` and `having`...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,value2   TINYINT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (name,value2) VALUES
('cust A',1),
('cust A',0),
('cust B',0),
('cust B',0),
('cust C',0),
('cust D',0),
('cust D',1),
('cust E',1),
('cust E',1);  

SELECT DISTINCT x.name
              , x.value2 
           FROM my_table x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.name = x.name 
            AND y.value2 = 1 
          WHERE x.value2 = 0 
            AND y.id IS NULL;
+--------+--------+
| name   | value2 |
+--------+--------+
| cust B |      0 |
| cust C |      0 |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, using `group by` with a `having` clause.

```
select name, 0 as value2
from table t
group by name
having max(value2) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, value2 from table t where value2 = 0 group by name;
```

You are correct. 'cust D' will not be eliminated by above query.
To eliminate 'cust D', you can use having clause as shown below:

```
select name, value2 from table t where value2 = 0 group by name having count(value2) > 1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also report "cust D"?

Comment: yup. this can't give result i want.